# Bloquear envio de formulário quando clicar em voltar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Pode parecer uma pergunta besta mas estou abismado que quando clico no botão voltar, o formulário é enviado.

O código é similar a este:

```
<form id="idform" method="post" onsubmit="return funcaodevalidacao(this);">
    <!-- conteúdo do form -->
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"> <button onclick="window.location.href = 'URL'">Voltar</button>
</form>
<script>
    $('form').submit(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

O que acontece é o seguinte: quando clico em Voltar, que deveria me redirecionar para uma URL desejada, o formulário é ENVIADO, e logo em seguida é redirecionado para a URL, o que não estou entendendo é o porque do formulário estar sendo enviado.

Já tentei a forma descrita acima para usar o preventDefault, desabilitar o beforeunload, retornar false, mas o formulário ainda assim é enviado.

Como faço para bloquear este comportamento? estou testando no firefox.

PS:  a função: funcaodevalidacao(this) está retornando false por questões de teste.
A solução paliativa que encontrei foi remover o elemento 'form', mas acredito que essa não seja a alternativa correta. Verifiquei no link http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12 que desabilitar o elemento  também não é possível.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade a forma que estava utilizando no exemplo acima adiciona uma segunda chamada de submit onde na verdade impede o envio formulário mas mesmo assim ainda chama a função de validação.

A solução mais correta que pensei neste caso foi adicionar este script ao botão voltar:

```
$('form').attr('onsubmit','return false;');window.location.href='URL'
```

Desta forma sobrescreve a função de validação que dava a impressão que o formulário estava sendo enviado.